# WebDAV disabled but still getting PROPFIND error

Tags: configuration

I have a Sitecore 8.2 site. WebDav is disabled on the CD as per

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/disable-webdav.html#

by disabling the Sitecore.WebDAV.config.

But the error logs are still full of this error:

```
7848 03:18:25 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.NotSupportedException
Message: Unknown request type: PROPFIND
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.WebHelper.GetRequestType(HttpContextBase httpContext)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Request.RequestBegin.ExecuteFormHandler.Process(RequestBeginArgs args)
at (Object , Object[] )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Which I think is a WebDAV error. Do I need to do something else to disable WebDAV? Or os this error from something else?

Comment: There are a couple of WebDav handlers in `web.config`. The docs _used_ to state to disable these too, but the latest doc does not mention this... you could try commenting these out too.

Comment: Here is nice article it may be helpful. https://sitecoresysadmin.wordpress.com/2017/09/01/webdav-must-be-disabled-on-content-delivery-server/